# Taks "GenerateResource" -- FAILED if amount of png images increases in Resources Visual studio, visual basic no error

Tags: vba, build, visual-studio-2015, resources

If the amount of added existing png images 30 MB  in the Rescource folder of a Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 project, than the build fails on my computer. The following steps are taken to include an existing image:
Project -> *Project_name* Properties -> Resources -> Add Existing File -> ....png.

No errors or warnings are shown, the output is as followed:
Processing resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" into "obj\Debug\Tweede_poging.Resources.resources". (TaskId:17)
1>Done executing task "GenerateResource" -- FAILED. (TaskId:17)

I've tried the following steps:
- Clean solution
- deleted bin folder, obj folder, Resources.rsx and .suo files
- increased the memory by using editbin and /LARGEADDRESSAWARE, before the implementation the maximum memory used for MSBuild.exe was +- 2.000.0000 kB afterwords it was +- 2.300.000 Kb

The computer which i'm using has the following properties:
Windows 7 Professional, 3 GB RAM
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Version (Verison 14.0.24720.00 Update 1) 
The code is Visual basic, 1 solution and 1 project is created.

There are no errors in the code. The only thing which causes the build to fail is the amount of png images. Does anyone has a suggestions to solve this problem? Is there a possibilty to link the png files instead of adding them into the project?

With kind regards

Comment: Can you increase [build verbosity](http://sedodream.com/2008/06/16/ChangingBuildVerbosityInVisualStudio.aspx)? There is a chance that you receive useful information about failure.

Comment: VBA is *NOT* VB.NET. Please tag your questions correctly, not only for those of us who don't want to see your question, but for yourself, so that the right people who perhaps can answer see your question!